# Stripping lines which don't include a text phrase

Tags: regex, terminal

Starting with a .txt file with lines like

```
adfgnfghqueendsfgdfg
dfgdfgdfg
gdfgdfgfhsfqueenjkhkjhkjg
hksad,jfhgkfdg
```

How would I strip the lines which don't have 'queen' in them? (preferably using an OS X Terminal command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` as:

1. Print only lines that have `queen` in them and make changes inline.

   ```
   sed  -i -n '/queen/p' file
   ```
2. Delete lines that do not have `queen` in them and make changes inline.

   ```
   sed  -i '/queen/!d' file
   ```

The above command delete if they find the word `queen` anywhere in the line, even as a part of another word. If this is not what you want and you want to delete only those lines where `queen` appears a separate word and not as part of another word you can make use of word boundaries `\b`as:

```
sed  -i -n '/\bqueen\b/p' file
sed  -i '/\bqueen\b/!d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep). For example:

```
grep "queen" file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: this one would **include** the line he doesn't want. You'll need to add a -v to filter them **out**

Comment: @Valentin: He want to strip lines that don't have queen == he wants to keep lines that have queen.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/queen/ d' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```